# Splitting a binary number using R

Tags: r, binary

Can I can get help with the following problem:

If I have a binary number `000111001010111` , for example, and I want it so that I have the output as `[0001], [1], [1], [001], [01], [01], [11]`. If anyone can help me with this, that would be great!

Comment: Why the `[11]` at the end but the `[1][1]` towards the beginning? The logic of the splitting is unclear.

Comment: Also, how is your binary number given to you?   As a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you want output as a list

```
text <- "000111001010111"

library(stringr)
str_split(str_replace_all(text, "1", "1,"), ",")
[[1]]
[1] "0001" "1"    "1"    "001"  "01"   "01"   "1"    "1"    ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `[11]` at the end was a typo and you want to spilt into substrings which consist of possibly some `'0'` followed by a single `'1'`, you can use the regular expression `'0*1'`:

```
library(stringr)
s <- '000111001010111'
unlist(str_extract_all(s,'0*1'))

#returns "0001"   "1"    "1"    "001"  "01"   "01"  "1"    "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strsplit`.

```
strsplit(x, "0?1\\K", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "0001" "1"    "1"    "001"  "01"   "01"   "1"    "1"
```